# ios swift program flow

Tags: ios, json, swift

In my mainviewcontroller's viewDidLoad() method I am firing few processes.

```
        let api = JsonData() // create instance of JsonData class
        api.loadJson(nil) // this method receives json and writes it in the file.

    //Function to find file location
    func getFileURL(fileName: String) -> NSURL {
        let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirURL = manager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)
        return dirURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }
         //file with this name was created in loadJson method
        let filePath = getFileURL("JSONFromServer.txt").path!

   //trying to read this file
 let newDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as! [Dictionary <String,AnyObject> ]
```

I was expecting that file will be created in `api.loadJson` and straight after it I will be able to read it. But for some reason when I use debugger I see that there is no file yet. And only when program goes out from viewdidload method I can see that file was created.

I wonder if program flow is specific?

Here is my JsonData class:

```
import Foundation

class JsonData {

    var bankDict  = [Dictionary <String,AnyObject> ]()
    var arrayOfBanks: [[String:AnyObject]] = []

    func loadJson(completion: ((AnyObject) -> Void)!) {

        var urlString = "http://almaz.com/getjson.php"

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let sourceUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)

        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(sourceUrl!){

            (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    println(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {

                    var error: NSError?

                    var jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &error) as! NSArray

                    //println(jsonData)


                    //convert from JSON into array of dictionaries
                    var rates = [ExchangeRates]()  //instance of class Rate
                    var bnkDct  =  ["bank": "", "currency": "","buyrate": "", "sellrate": ""] //template
                    var indx : Int = 0 //index for iteration

                    for rate in jsonData{
                        let rate = ExchangeRates(rate as! NSDictionary)

                        rates.append(rate)

                            bnkDct["bank"] = rates[indx].bank
                            bnkDct["buyrate"] = rates[indx].buyRate
                            bnkDct["sellrate"] = rates[indx].sellRate
                            bnkDct["currency"] = rates[indx].currency

                        self.bankDict.append(bnkDct)
                        indx += 1
                }

                //println(self.bankDict)



                //Store data in file
                //File path and name
                if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
                        let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
                        let filePath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("JSONFromServer.txt");

                    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self.bankDict, toFile: filePath)
                   // println(filePath)
                    }


            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where you are, otherwise I would come to your office, look over your shoulder, and find out what you are talking about. Since I can't, could you show us where JsonData comes from and so on and so on, because the information you give us here is frankly completely useless.

Comment: Most likely the downloading of the JSON data is being done asynchronously so you can't attempt to read the file immediately after calling `loadJson`.

Comment: There are so many Json libraries with similar naming schemes that it's impossible to guess which one you're using.

Comment: Guys sorry. Check updated question. hope it will make sense now

Comment: Nope. You need to tell us which JSON library you're using, and provide a link to info about that library. As others have suggested, it's likely that your JSON library's loadJson call is operating asynchronously, but we can't tell without more info.

Comment: @DuncanC just added additional code.

Comment: @DuncanC any ideas why it finishes only with viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Now that you've provided more information @rmaddy was the first to point out the problem with your code. You need to restructure so that you use the completion handler to your loadJson method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadJson` function takes a completion handler as a parameter but your `loadJson` function doesn't call it when it is done. Fix that first.

Then in your `viewDidLoad` function, pass in a completion handler when you call `loadJson`. The completion code you provide is where you should read and process the file saved by `loadJson`.